# Valgrind: Invalid write of size 8 coming from copy constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, char, valgrind

I'm using valgrind to try and fix the many memory leaks in an assignment I'm working on and it's giving me a few different read/write/uninitialized value errors. I *think* I know where it's coming from based on the valgrind output, but cannot figure out how to fix it for the life of me. I'm very new to C++ so I'm probably just doing something totally incorrect with how I'm allocating (and then trying to access the incorrectly allocated memory) the memory for the array, but I can't figure out what exactly that would be.

Here's the various valgrind outputs:

```
Invalid write of size 8
==13371==    at 0x4013F5: family::setFriends(char**) (family.cpp:62)
==13371==    by 0x401231: family::family(family const&) (family.cpp:31)
==13371==    by 0x402358: hashtable::node::node(family const&) (hashtable.h:29)
==13371==    by 0x401E81: hashtable::insert(char const*, family const&) (hashtable.cpp:87)
==13371==    by 0x4018CD: familymgr::addFamily(family&) (familymgr.cpp:15)
==13371==    by 0x402779: main (housinghelper.cpp:86)
==13371==  Address 0x5ad1810 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 32 free'd
==13371==    at 0x4C2F650: operator delete[](void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:621)
==13371==    by 0x4013B5: family::setFriends(char**) (family.cpp:60)
==13371==    by 0x401231: family::family(family const&) (family.cpp:31)
==13371==    by 0x402358: hashtable::node::node(family const&) (hashtable.h:29)
==13371==    by 0x401E81: hashtable::insert(char const*, family const&) (hashtable.cpp:87)
==13371==    by 0x4018CD: familymgr::addFamily(family&) (familymgr.cpp:15)
==13371==    by 0x402779: main (housinghelper.cpp:86)
==13371==  Block was alloc'd at
==13371==    at 0x4C2E8BB: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:423)
==13371==    by 0x40120F: family::family(family const&) (family.cpp:29)
==13371==    by 0x402358: hashtable::node::node(family const&) (hashtable.h:29)
==13371==    by 0x401E81: hashtable::insert(char const*, family const&) (hashtable.cpp:87)
==13371==    by 0x4018CD: familymgr::addFamily(family&) (familymgr.cpp:15)
==13371==    by 0x402779: main (housinghelper.cpp:86)
```

Uninitialized value message:

```
Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==13371==    at 0x401E98: hashtable::insert(char const*, family const&) (hashtable.cpp:90)
==13371==    by 0x4018CD: familymgr::addFamily(family&) (familymgr.cpp:15)
==13371==    by 0x402779: main (housinghelper.cpp:86)
==13371==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==13371==    at 0x401882: familymgr::addFamily(family&) (familymgr.cpp:11)
==13371== 
==13371== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==13371==    at 0x401EB9: hashtable::insert(char const*, family const&) (hashtable.cpp:91)
==13371==    by 0x4018CD: familymgr::addFamily(family&) (familymgr.cpp:15)
==13371==    by 0x402779: main (housinghelper.cpp:86)
==13371==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==13371==    at 0x401882: familymgr::addFamily(family&) (familymgr.cpp:11)
```

'friends' is a char** member variable declared in the header file as so:

```
char **friends;
```

Everything seems to be stemming from the copy-constructor:

```
family::family(const family &fam) : ID(NULL), famName(NULL), 
friends(NULL){
    setID(fam.ID); 
    setFamName(fam.famName);
    setMembers(fam.members);
    setCapacity(fam.capacity);
    setNumFriends(fam.numFriends);

    setFriends(fam.friends);
}
```

Here is the main constructor, just incase I did not properly allocate memory for `friends` right from the get-go:

```
    family::family(char *ID, char *famName, int members) :
    ID(NULL),
    famName(NULL),
    members(members),
    numFriends(-1),
    capacity(DEFAULT_CAPACITY)
{
    friends = new char*[capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < numFriends; i++)
        friends[i] = NULL;

    setID(ID);
    setFamName(famName);
}
```

And here is the `setFriends` function that is being referenced:

```
void family::setFriends(char** friendIn){
friends = new char*[sizeof(friendIn[0])/numFriends];
if(friends!=NULL)
    delete [] friends;
for (int i = 0; i < capacity;i++){
    this->friends[i] = friendIn[i];
    }
}

bool familymgr::addFamily(family &inputFam) {
    char fam[100];
    inputFam.getID(fam);

    table->insert(fam, inputFam);
}
```

getID:

```
void family::getID(char *id) const {
    strcpy(id, this->ID);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here to produce all these errors?

Comment: Those valgrind errors do not describe leaks. Always focus on the first error first - is that the first one you posted?

Comment: @aschepler yeah my mistake. I said leaks because I do have a ton of memory leakage, but I assume that memory leakage is coming from the errors that I posted.

Comment: Where's the code for `addFamily`?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm added that method at the bottom

Comment: That's calling `getId` to initialize `fam`, which leads to: What's the code for `family::getId`?

Comment: I suspect this is assignment where the *real* way to code a solution to what this seems to be doing would be to use RAII and standard library containers and objects. Nearly all of this would simply disappear. If you're *not* under such neanderthal constraints, I would do so. If you're up for the challenge of doing it like you are (or are required to do so), I urge you to also read about the [Rule of Three/Five/Zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). It will become *very* important sooner or later.

Comment: `void family::getID(char *id) const {
    strcpy(id, this->ID);
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `setFriends` method writes to memory that you do not own:

```
void family::setFriends(char** friendIn){
    friends = new char*[sizeof(friendIn[0])/numFriends];
    if(friends!=NULL) // <-- This will always be true, since friends was
                      //     assigned a non-null value in the new[]
                      //     expression above
        delete [] friends;  // <-- Here you free the memory you just allocated
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity;i++){
        // At this point, friends is no longer pointing to a valid object
        // so you are trying to write to memory you don't own
        this->friends[i] = friendIn[i];
    }
}
```

You should reverse the check for `NULL` and the `new[]` expression.  Also, using `sizeof(friendIn[0])/numFriends` makes no sense.  `sizeof(friendIn[0]` will always be 4 or 8, depending on the bitness of your platform.  I'm guessing that should just be `capacity`:

```
void family::setFriends(char** friendIn){
    if(friends != nullptr) {
        delete [] friends;
    }
    friends = new char*[capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity;i++){
        this->friends[i] = friendIn[i];
    }
}
```

This will work when called from the copy constructor, but keep in mind that you're still making a shallow copy of `friends`.  Both `family` objects will point to the same strings, and if you later `delete[]` those strings then any object still pointing to them will not work.  You should really just make `friends` a `std::vector<std::string>>` instead of doing all of this manual memory management.  Then you could make `setFriends` much simpler and much safer:

```
void family::setFriends(std::vector<std::string>> friendIn) {
    friends = std::move(friendIn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Invalid Write comes from `setFriends`, where you delete the memory allocated to `friends` then write to it.  You need to do a new allocation in `setFriends` before copying in the friends.

The uninitialized value messages come about because you have two variables named `ID` in the `family` constructor: the parameter, and the class member.  When you call `setID(ID)`, this is referencing the class member (with a value of NULL), *not* the parameter `ID`.  Rename the parameters to have different names from the fields in the class.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding, didn't I already do a new allocation for `friends` with `friends = new char*[sizeof(fam.friends[0])/numFriends];` in the copy constructor?

Comment: That's in the constructor.  That memory is deleted (freed) with `delete [] friends` in `setFriends`, and you need to allocate new memory before you can use it again.

Comment: @ThomasJazz `delete [] friends` followed immediately thereafter by dereferencing, i.e: `this->friends[i] = ...` is a *recipe* for undefined behavior. In fact, it is guaranteed. Read about dynamic object lifetime in your text.